# Qt: How can I open the text file in relative path?

Tags: qt, c++11

```
QFile file("../studentdata/students.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly| QIODevice::Text);

qDebug()<<file.isOpen()<<file.isReadable()<<file.isWritable();
```

I want to open the file students.txt with relative path, but the qDebug result is false false false

Comment: does it work if you pass absolute path to QFile constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619517/qfile-wont-open-the-file

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory may not be what you expect. Check it with `QDir::currentPath()` . Also check the `QFile` error string, so print `file.errorString()` after failed opening. For instance your application may not have permissions to write to this file.

Answer (score -2):

```
 QFile file("studentdata\students.txt");
 file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly| QIODevice::Text);
```

change the slash - it prints true, false, true. (: